# How to resolve "Use of unresolved identifier 'PresentationLink'" error in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

In swiftUI, I tried to create a PresentationLink button but after updated xcode in beta 5, I have the "Use of unresolved identifier 'PresentationLink'" error. I don't know why.

'PresentationLink' it is deprecated and has it been replaced by nother name? I did not find in the documentation.

[image: screenshot of xcode]

My code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct NavBar : View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Image("navigation_border")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
      HStack {
        Spacer()

        // Compass button
        Button(action: {
          // Code here
        }) {
          Image("ic_compass")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: CGFloat(35), height: CGFloat(35), alignment: .center)
          Text("Boussole")
            .foregroundColor(Color("TextLight"))
            .font(.system(size: 14))
            .fixedSize()
        }
        .frame(height: CGFloat(50), alignment: .bottomLeading)

        Spacer()

        // Travel button
        Button(action: {
          // Code here
        }) {
          Image("ic_travel")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: CGFloat(35), height: CGFloat(35), alignment: .center)
          Text("Parcours")
            .foregroundColor(Color("TextLight"))
            .font(.system(size: 14))
            .fixedSize()
        }
        .frame(height: CGFloat(50), alignment: .bottomLeading)

        Spacer()

        // Settings button
        PresentationLink(destination: Settings()) {
          Image("ic_settings")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 32, height: 32, alignment: .center)
          Text("Paramètres")
            .foregroundColor(Color("TextLight"))
            .font(.system(size: 14))
            .fixedSize()
        }
        .frame(height: 50, alignment: .bottomLeading)

        Spacer()

      }
      .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 70, maxHeight: 70, alignment: .center)
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 90, maxHeight: 90, alignment: .center)
  }
}
```

I made latest update of MacOS Catalina.

Tank you for your help.

Comment: First, I **strongly** recommend updating to Xcode beta 6, which came out earlier this week. Yes, both `PresentationButton` and `PresentationLink` are now fully deprecated. The warning you received in beta 4 is now an error. Look into using the `sheet` modifier. I don't have time right now to alter your code into an answer, but I know I've already answered a similar question recently, so maybe searching on *[swiftui] sheet* will yield some good results. Good luck!

Comment: Just don't put `.sheet` inside a `List`, otherwise it can only be opened once.